# how to make array of image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

how to make nsmutablearray of image from the camera?

Example: When a user selects an **image** from the **camera** so it will be added to an array

**I want to do something like a photo album**

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pick images from your library or take new once with the camera and then add them to an array, a good starting point would be the [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).

But the way you ask your question implies that you should start out with some [basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html) about iOS development.